# Get indexes of longest repeated string

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
l = [True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False]
```

How do I get the indexes of the longest repeated substring `True` ?

The output would be: `[3,4,5]`

**This is what I have tried:**

```
get_index=[]
counter = 0
for i,li in enumerate(l):
    if li == True:
        counter = counter +1
        get_index.append([i,counter])
    else:
        counter = 0
```

I get a list like that: `[[0, 1], [1, 2], [3, 1], [4, 2], [5, 3]]`

Now the idea is to retain only the pairs where the left numbers are increasing without interruption (i.e. 3,4,5) and where the last right number has the highest score of all pairs. … but I don't know how to do that?

Comment: As you should know with 406 reputation points, StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service, so please edit the code you have tried to write into your question.

Comment: @barny Will do it.

Comment: Shouldn't have to tell you.

Comment: I don't understand the output and how it is related to True False sequence. I see 2 'True' or 3 'True'. Even indexes don't match.

Comment: @barny Please have a look at my updated question. Thanks. :)

Comment: What if the sequence is is heavy in False? Do you want the longest sequence of a specific value only or longest of any value?

Comment: @perennial_noob The longest of a specific value, which is "True" in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
clusters = [[]]
for index, b in enumerate(l):
    if b:
        # Append to the existing cluster if this item is True
        clusters[-1].append(index)
    elif clusters[-1]:
        # If this item is False, finalize the previous cluster and init
        # a new empty one (but don't bother if the previous cluster was
        # already empty)
        clusters.append([])

# Print the longest cluster
print(max(clusters, key=len))
```

Comment: No need to create a lambda here, you can pass `key=len`

Comment: That's true, thanks! I'm so used to automatically using lambdas for stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer !